# Ubuntu stopped working with a dual boot setup

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot on top of Windows 8.1. Was working fine for a few days. But now what I see after a restart is a grub command line. When I type `exit` I get windows started right away. What could be the reason for that and how could I get back a grub dual boot option?

Comment: @karel I have an opposite situation - can start windows but not ubuntu

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a live USB flash drive that you used to install Ubuntu 14.04, you can boot from the Ubuntu live USB and run Boot Repair to repair the GRUB bootloader.

From the Ubuntu live USB, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

[image]

Boot Repair is available from ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: found this solution somewhere on ubuntu forum a moment ago, let's see if it works

Comment: U saved my day, thx! Any ideas how to stop windows to mess with the boot manager?

Comment: [Update Windows 8 broke my GRUB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/483531/update-windows-8-broke-my-grub/483732#483732). This answer is based on looking at the results of the Boot Repair Boot Info Script. Your Boot Repair Boot Info Script may be different, so I suggest that you also search for it in the other answers of [Rod Smith](http://superuser.com/users/171594/rod-smith), who is an expert on this topic.